# How to use .Top() with Code First

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, code-first

Is this possible with Code First? I could do this if I only used Entity Framework:

```
var q = from m in context.Products
            .Top("0")
             select m;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code-first is more about how you define your model and map it to your database.  Querying is a separate topic entirely, and whether you use model-first, code-first or the new "POCO" support in the CTP, querying should be exactly the same.

In your case, assuming you have a querying problem rather than a code-first problem, I think you'd write it slightly differently as:

```
var query = context.Products.Take(1);
```

Although if you're doing this you probably want the actual item itself, so this might be more appropriate:

```
Product product = context.Products.Take(1).SingleOrDefault();

if (product == null) // Do something...

DoSomethingWithProduct(product);
```

Comment: Thank you, using Take() does work. Maybe I'm missing something, because Top() does not work when I switched over to Code First, querying over IDbSet<type> (POCO) instead of an entity generated by the Entity Framework designer. Take() uses the extension IQueryable<type>, while Top() uses System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery. Is it still possible to use Top() somehow?

Comment: Code First is based around LINQ and the LINQ syntax for this functionality is Take which is functionally equivalent. You could case the underlying DbSet to ObjectQuery and then call Top but I really wouldn't recommend it.